# How to save user to database in spring- workflow

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a DAO:

```
package phcare_project.dao;

public interface UserI {

    void save(String firstName, String lastName);
    UserI findByID(int id);
}
```

its implementation

```
package phcare_project.repository;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import phcare_project.dao.UserI;
@Repository
public class User implements UserI {

    @Override
    public void save(String firstName, String lastName) {
        System.out.println("Saved to the db!");
        System.out.println( "Hello " + firstName + lastName);
    }

    @Override
    public UserI findByID(int id) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

entity:

```
package phcare_project.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class UserE {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="pwz_number")
    private int pwz_number;
    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    public UserE(int id, String firstName, String lastName, int pwz_number, String city) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.pwz_number = pwz_number;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getPwz_number() {
        return pwz_number;
    }

    public void setPwz_number(int pwz_number) {
        this.pwz_number = pwz_number;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public UserE() {
    }

}
```

Request:

```
package phcare_project.dto;

public class CreateUserRequest {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

}

and the controller:

```
package phcare_project.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import phcare_project.dao.UserI;
import phcare_project.dto.CreateUserRequest;
import phcare_project.entity.UserE;

@RestController
public class userController {

    public UserI currentUserI;
    @Autowired
    public userController(UserI theUserI){
        currentUserI = theUserI;
    };

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String HelloUser(){
        return "Hello from phcare";
    }

//    @PostMapping("/createUser")
//    public String createUser(@RequestBody CreateUserRequest request) {
//        String firstName = request.getFirstName();
//        String lastName = request.getLastName();
//
//        currentUserI.save(firstName, lastName);
//        return "Zapisano użytkownika: " + firstName + " " + lastName;
//    }

}
```

and i want to save it to the database using after Post request with data;
But i dont really understand the workflow:

1. create a controller for API endpoint
2. create a DAO for class abstraction
3. implement DAO
4. create a request body with its own fields..

and then what?

is it that complicated in Spring to save a simple file? what are basics steps to to it? how to implement it? I am connected to db already.

Comment: `is it that complicated in Spring to save a simple file?`, yes, when you're working on your first spring playground code, no, when you are on a 500+ classes, 10+ developers software project and must keep a clear view of what is happening. I advise you, to work on some spring(boot) JPA tutorials https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql

Comment: sir thats gold that you brought me! sir yes sir thanks! i will read it!